# Bash - Read and write to an interactive telnet session

Tags: bash, bots, telnet

I am making a program that will start a telnet session and reads questions and sends the answers, then reads the new output. For example, this would be a telnet session:
50*2584 
(Answer)
38/3.63
(Answer)
And etc.
My question is: How can I read the question as it appears, or is there any way to write an expect script without knowing what to expect?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask us a question. What is it you need help with? Or were you looking for somebody to write it for you?

Comment: @RobertSeaman Sorry, I hope this last edit helped

Comment: Do you really want a *telnet* session, vs a raw socket? The easy way to do this is `socat` invoking your script with stdin and stdout connected to the remote socket. Telnet is a surprisingly complex protocol, most of which the client isn't speaking whenever you use the telnet client to connect to anything that isn't a telnet server.

Comment: ("easy way" != "only way"; If your bash is compiled with `/dev/tcp`, it's certainly possible to use that directly).